# How to filter and sort a List using another List in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

My code

```
val list1 = getAllCheckingPoints() 
val list2 = getselectedCheckingPoints()
```

say list1 is of Type1 and list2 is of Type2

Type1 is a data class that contains id,name,type,duration

Type2 is a data class that contains only id and position

both contain ids that match but **only list 2 contains the positions**

so I create an empty list

```
var filteredList: List<Type1> = emptyList()


 filteredList = list2.flatMap { list2Item->
                list1.filter { list1Item ->
                    list1Item.id == list2Item.id
                }
            }
```

Here I am trying is to make the filteredList a list of Type1 that has only the
items from list1 that are present in list2 with matching the ids. I am stuck
after this step.

how do I sort the filteredList with the position values present in list2 ?

Comment: This would be easier to follow if you could boil it down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Do I understand that you want to sort one list so that its items appear in the same order as they do in another list?  If so, what about items that _don't_ appear in the other list; where you want those to go?

Comment: `position` is a field of `Type2` or an index of object in `list2`?

Comment: its a field@МихаилНафталь

Comment: @gidds please see my updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need filter out all items of `list1` with ids absent in `list2` and sort them based on some property of `list2` object.

1. Convert second list into map with key=id, value=position:

```kotlin
val map = list2.associate { it.id to it.position }
```

2. Use this map for filtering and sorting:

```kotlin
val result = list1.filter { it.id in map }.sortedBy { map[it.id] }
```

Comment: it worked thank you so much!. I'm curious what if the postions were to come from an index of objects what would be different ?

Comment: the map would be different: `val map = list2.withIndex().associate { it.value.id to it.index }`